# In Activity, is it ever fine to access savedInstanceState before super.onCreate?

Tags: android, android-fragments

If we perform rotation, here's is sequence of code execution for Activity and Fragment.

1. Activity's `super.onCreate()`
2. Fragment's `super.onCreate()`
3. Fragment's all custom user code after `super.onCreate()`
4. Activity's all custom user code after `super.onCreate()`

If we have a `savedInstanceState` restored variable in Activity, being accessed by Fragment, we need to initialize it before Activity's `super.onCreate()`

### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public int variable = 0;

    MainFragment mainFragment = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Is it ever Ok to perform accessing to savedInstanceState, before
        // super.onCreate?
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            this.variable = savedInstanceState.getInt("VARIABLE");
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mainFragment = new MainFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();
        } else {
            mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        savedInstanceState.putInt("VARIABLE", variable);
    }
}
```

---

### MainFragment

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "In MainFragment, accessing variable from MainActivity -> " + ((MainActivity)getActivity()).variable);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

---

However, such technique (Access savedInstanceState before Activity's super.onCreate) is not being mentioned in the official documentation. I was wondering, is it ever Ok to do so? Is there any edge cases I will encounter?

Comment: I haven't seen any documentation discouraging such practice. I would say you'll never hit any edge cases simply because the `Bundle` you provide in this line `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` means acquiring and passing "ready" saved instance to super class is the responsibility of the derived class. So it must always be acquired before passing it to the super class.